# Functions syntax seems ok, code not working (functions.php)

Tags: php, wordpress, string

Trying to get a function working for wordpress. Using a little bit of code. Problems with syntax or something. Code is in wordpress functions.php. Output should be a text link with the product-id in it. So after click on link the url wil be example: http://www.websitenname.com/interesse?id=33

I have tested this code with-in a template (single-product woocommerce) with succes. This should now work in functions.php for another project (using a short-code in a template (wordpress)) Maybe someone know's what I'm doing wrong

```
function vComp(){
<a class="interessebutton" href="http://www.websitenname.com/interesse?id=<?php echo $product->id; ?>">Interesse</a>
}
add_shortcode( 'vInteresse', 'vComp' );
```

Hope to learn what I'm doing wrong. Syntax error: syntax error, unexpected 'vInteresse' (T_STRING)

Comment: you cannot simply include raw HTML in your PHP function. It needs to be output with `echo` or another similar function. Also, I'd guess that `$product` is undefined within the body of your `vComp` function

Comment: should be: $aq = get_post_meta($product->id <a class="interessebutton" href="http://www.websitename.com/interesse?id=<?php echo $product->id; ?>">Interesse</a>

Comment: Not knowing how to make this valid code. Using echo.. stuck in the dark here.. just learning :)

Comment: Easiest option would be breaking out of PHP mode within the function body, as in: `?> <a class… </a> <?php`. // Though as Ramraider points out, you'll likely need a `return` than direct output. Thus read up on string syntax/operations in the manual.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea about the internal workings of Wordpress whatsoever but the cited function is wrong on a couple of levels. Perhaps look at the following to see if it does what you need - or gets you closer.

```
function vComp($product=false, $title=false){
    return $product && $title && is_object( $product ) && property_exists( $product, 'id' ) ? sprintf('<a class="interessebutton" href="/interesse?id=%s">%s</a>', $product->id, $title ) : false;
}
```

The function here will `return` a value which can then be used by the Wordpress function `add_shortcode` - whether this is what was intended or not I cannot say for sure.

Essentially the function says "if there is a product ( which is an object and has an ID attribute ) and a title - return the html link"

After looking more closely I suspect the above would not have worked ( unless it is possible to supply addition args to the Wordpress function `add_shortcode` ) so:

```
function vComp(){
    global $product;
    return $product && is_object( $product ) && property_exists( $product, 'id' ) ? sprintf('<a class="interessebutton" href="/interesse?id=%s">Interesse</a>', $product->id ) : false;
}
```

Comment: I've tried this, not working. No output.. no syntax or other errors.. that's a good step forward in a way..

Comment: looking at what I posted and then looking at `add_shortcode( 'vInteresse', 'vComp' );` leads me to think this will not actually work as one would appear unable to add parameters to the `add_shortcode` function